# React - counting checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having some trouble with some checkboxes in my React component here: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiz-4uyde?file=/src/App.js

The problem I am getting is that when two correct answers are checked, the score is not being reflected correctly. I am trying to have it set up so that when a correct answer is checked, the score is increased by one. that increase should be removed when the correct answer is unchecked. Any the score should not be increased or decrease if an incorrect answer is checked. however, on the first question here, when I check one correct answer the score is increased, but when I check a second correct answer, the score is decreased.

If any has input, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `useState` to track the `checked` answers throughout the quiz.
In order to do that I've moved whole questions into the `useState` and added a new property to each `checked: false`.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(initialQuestions);
```

For managing user click you have a function `handleAnswerOptionClick`. The main takeaway from this function is that only clicked answer should have it's `checked` state toggled (`checked: !previousCheckedValue`). In relation to questions with type `select` when the user clicks on one question all others will be unchecked automatically.

```
const handleAnswerOptionClick = (e, questionId) => {
const answerTextValue = e.target.value;
const updatedQuestions = questions.map((question) => {
  if (question.id === questionId) {
    const updatedAnswersOptions = question.answerOptions.map((answer) => {
      if (answer.answerText === answerTextValue) {
        return { ...answer, checked: !answer.checked };
        } else {
          return question.questionType === "select"
            ? { ...answer, checked: false }
            : answer;
        }
      });
      return { ...question, answerOptions: updatedAnswersOptions };
      } else {
       return question;
      }
    });
    setQuestions(updatedQuestions);
  };
```

In addition to managing the `checked` state, you can also include the `useMemo` hook to calculate the number of correct answers inside all questions. Please note that if the answer has selected multiple correct answers for a certain question the score will be increased by a number of correct answers.

```
    const score = useMemo(() => {
    return questions.reduce((acc, q) => {
      const correctAnswerSelected = q.answerOptions.reduce((acc, answer) => {
        if (answer.checked && answer.isCorrect) {
          acc = acc + 1;
        }
        return acc;
      }, 0);
      acc = acc + correctAnswerSelected;

      return acc;
    }, 0);
  }, [questions]);
```

Here's the working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiz-forked-vbt6o?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for your help. The only thing is that on question 1, if both of the correct answers are selected, it only shows "1" for the score

Comment: And you want it to count as 2?

Comment: yeah i would like it to count as 2

Comment: I edited an answer, the change is inside `useMemo`. Good luck :)

Comment: i see the updated sandbox, and it does work now. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be handling the state wrong. What you are doing is setting static items and checking on click if they are correct, but not if they aren't. this way here are whats hapenning wrong:

1. You're not tracking what is and isn't checked
2. You're not tracking a wrong answer, only if the answer is clicked.

What you could do instead, is set the checked inside you answerOptions:

```js
answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "New York", isCorrect: false, checked: false },
        { answerText: "London", isCorrect: false, checked: false },
        { answerText: "Paris", isCorrect: true, checked: false },
        { answerText: "Dublin", isCorrect: true, checked: false }
      ]
```

Then, in your handleChange, pass the item and change the checked value to true.

After that, all you have to do is update the score:

```
setScore(score.filter(a => a.isCorrect && a.checked).length)
```

`Note that this won't remove point for wrong answers, but you can also have it this way`

```
setScore(answers.filter(a => a.isCorrect && a.checked).length - answers.filter(a => !a.isCorrect && a.checked).length)
```

and set answers to the current Question's answers

**Edit**

Forgot to mention about the answers in the last part.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is really helpful. Could you explain a little more on how you would update the handleChange?

Comment: First of all, your checked value should be set to the checked property of you answerOption.
Second, in your handleChange, you should update the state to reflect that the answer is now checked
Third, you update the score

Big problem right now, wich is also why I don't really use hooks, is that your questions cannot be updated because they are props and therefore, immutable. You should consider haveing them in the state too, so they can be updated